# Is there a way to automatically update an RSpec expectation?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I'm wondering if this feature exists in RSpec. I can't seem to find any results when looking into it.

What I'd like to do is something that can be done in Jest tests like so:

```
// This is a Jest expectation

expect(foo).toMatchInlineSnapshot()

// On the first execution of this code, the value of foo will fill in the expectation and result in something like this

expect(foo).toMatchInlineSnapshot('bar')
```

I'd love to be able to do this with RSpec tests.

```
# Here's an RSpec expectation

expect(foo).to eq({ bar: 25 })
```

Say that I make a change to my code that will result in foo[:bar] having a different value, but I don't know what that value will be.

Currently, I need to re-run my tests and see an error saying something along the lines of

```
 Failure/Error: expect(foo).to eq({ bar: 25 })

       expected: { bar: 25 }
            got: { bar: 100 }
```

After that, I need to manually update my expectation in order for it to pass.

Is there anyway to tell RSpec to automatically update the expected value?

For Example:

```
expect(foo).to eq({ bar: 25 }, {update: true})
```

would change the code after running the test to match the correct value and result in the following code replacing the above expectation:

```
expect(foo).to eq({ bar: 100 })
```

Is there any existing way to accomplish this? Some command that I can run with RSpec maybe?

```
spec UPDATE_EXPECTS=1
```

I've seen libraries that can match based on snapshots, but haven't been able to find anything that results in the expected answer appearing inline.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Haven't heard of anything like this.

Comment: "but I don't know what that value will be" - that is a problem, indeed. Do you really _know_ what's happening in your code? How can you not know what it will produce?

Comment: Values may change from 25 to 26, or stay as 25 after changing a Math.floor to a Math.round. It's very tedious to go re-run my tests over and over to change 1 value at a time.

Comment: More tedious than go through the tests and insert `{update: true}` everywhere?

Comment: Looks like you could use some `aggregate_failures: true` too.

Comment: I don't know of this feature. And I don't think it's one I would like to have in the framework. Doing this as a one-off when first writing a spec may be useful, but only as a shortcut for manually copy+pasting a carefully selected (few?) failure messages into the expectation. Having a command like `spec UPDATE_EXPECTS=1` sounds like madness to me!

Comment: @TomLord: to put it mildly... :)

Comment: Digging deeper, the [tool you are describing](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing) was designed for *UI testing*. In such tests, it would be totally impractical to define the actual expectation; snapshot tests are only supposed to fail if _something_ changes (but you may not know/care what). What we are talking about here is *unit* tests, which is a totally different category of testing. In summary, this would be a very bad idea.

Comment: I think that it could be useful when used in combination with 'fit's as you could carefully look over the changes.

Comment: aggregate_failures can definitely help speed this up. Thank you @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this type of tool exists for RSpec. The closest you could maybe come is using a `let` or an instance variable at the top of your script.

```
let(:subtotal) { 25.0 } # can _maybe_ only update this if logic changed
let(:cart) { Cart.new }

before do
  cart.add_item(10.0)
  cart.add_item(15.0)
end

it do
  expect(cart.subtotal).to eq(subtotal)
end
```

You'd still have to manually curate the values when logic changes that would break the test assertion. There are already a number of matchers in RSpec that will let you do a looser assertion, such as [be_within](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/built-in-matchers/be-within-matcher), but nothing to automatically fill in values for you. The [include](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher) matcher is another powerful matcher that lets you do looser assertions.

I feel like updating values automatically would be equivalent to testing `expect(x).to eq(x)`. I'm not sure there's much value in that kind of test for what I've typically seen RSpec used for.

The reality is, your test should/will often fail when you make a change to your code. It's annoying that you have to go back and fix the test, but it should also reassuring that the test provided some value. I would be more alarmed if I changed code and didn't have a failing test...